# How to use Facebook's scraper together with safe_image.php script?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, facebook, scraper

I have a dynamic list of URLs, for each one of the URLs I AJAX POST (as described [**here**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/)) like so:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?id={object-url}&scrape=true
```

the JSON result I get contains an array of images, some are OK to use as a thumbnail others don't.

---

**Example**:

[image]

---

**Questions**:

1. Can I use Facebook's `https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php` script? How?
2. Is there another free scraper that offers similar capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

About the closest thing I can think of is to run the URL through Facebook's sharer.php and then grab the URL of the thumbnail image that is generated. Unfortunately that means another AJAX request for each URL...

e.g. for the url in the JSON result you posted:
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.liveperson.com/african-art-educator/

The img HTML element of the thumbnail image would be the following:

```
<img class="UIShareStage_Image img" src="https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBN-ZE_J_cPGKzs&amp;w=154&amp;h=154&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fexpertsimages.liveperson.com%2Fexperts-pictures%2Fbig%2Fpic0.jpg&amp;cfs=1&amp;upscale" alt="">
```

So you could parse the HTML response, and fetch the src attribute of the above element.

I've tried getting different sized thumbnails, but so far the only thing I've found that changes the size is adding or removing the `&cfs=1` query string variable you see there, which if it exists, uses a square-cropped version of the image.